# Insert , Update and Delete JSON object using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I have this JSON object .

```
json_elements = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

VALUE is :

```
  [{"pid":"2","qty":1,"Pname":"Jelly Doughnuts","uniteV":36},{"pid":"34","qty":1,"Pname":"Loukoumades Donuts","uniteV":9},{"pid":"32","qty":1,"Pname":"Bismark Doughnut","uniteV":6},{"pid":"34","qty":1,"Pname":"Loukoumades Donuts","uniteV":9},{"pid":"33","qty":1,"Pname":"Maple Bar Donuts","uniteV":3}]
```

Insert into JSON object is

```
                 obj.push({
                        pid: pid,
                        qty: qty,
                        Pname: Pname,
                        uniteV: uniteV
                    });
```

MY question is 
**CAN any one tell me HOW TO UPDATE AND DELETE operation done for exactly this JSON object?**

Answer (score 0):

Because you tagged this question with "jquery" I'm going to answer using jquery functions.

I think that what you are trying to ask is how can you use jquery to update/delete a specified object in your array of objects (note that your variable `obj` is actually an array of objects).  The jquery function `grep` is good for finding the correct object within an array of objects.  Once you find the correct object in the array you can simply update that object.

```
var myArray = obj; //you're really working with an array of objects instead of one objects
var result = $.grep(myArray, function(e){ return e.pid == pidToUpdate; });
if (result.length == 0) {
  // the object wasn't in the array of objects
} else if (result.length == 1) {
  // there was a single matching object, and we can now update whatever attribute we want
  result[0].attributeToUpdate = newValue
} else {
  // multiple items found.  Do with them whatever you want
};
```

You can use `grep` to delete an object from an array of objects. Alternatively, you could use `splice` like this:

```
$.each(myArray, function(i){
  if(myArray[i].pid == pidThatYouWantToDelete) {
      myArray.splice(i,1);
      return false;
  };
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @sourav-roy, do you have any questions about my answer?  Did it help you?  If I answered your question please make sure to "accept" my answer.  I've taken a look at your user profile and have seen that you have asked a total of 5 questions on SO, and haven't accepted a single answer.  That sort of behavior will make it very unlikely that anyone will attempt to help you in the future.

Comment: im not understanding your answer, how can you push items into this array?